# How long does Gmail keep read but unanswered messages in the Inbox?

Tags: gmail

How long does Gmail keep read, but unanswered messages in the Inbox?

Answer (score 31):

Indefinitely.

The only messages that Gmail automatically removes are those in *Trash* and *Spam*. Those are removed after they're there for 30 days.